# Solution to second order nonhomogeneous DE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve this differential equation using Mathematica:

```
1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
  em*V1[x] + (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep) == 0
```

The general solution of the nonhomogeneous equation can be found as follows:

```
SolGeneralNonHomo = 
 DSolve[1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] + (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep) == 0, 
  V1[x], x]
```

This should be equal to the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

The general solution of the homogeneous equation can be found as follows:

```
SolGeneralHomo = 
 DSolve[1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] == 0, V1[x], x]
```

A particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation can be found using the Variation of Parameters Formula. More precisely, given the nonhomogeneous equation:

$$a(x) y′′(x) + b(x) y′(x) + c(x) y(x) = f(x)$$

a particular solution is given by:

$$y1(x) \left( \int \frac{y2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} dx \right) + y2(x) \left( \int \frac{y1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} dx \right)$$

where $W(x)$ is the Wronskian:

$$W(x) = y1(x) y2′(x) - y1′(x) y2(x)$$

Therefore, I do exactly this in Mathematica:

```
a[x_] := 1/2*\[Sigma]X^2;
y1[x_] := 
  HermiteH[-(em/a1), (Sqrt[a1] x)/\[Sigma]X - (a0 \[Delta])/(
    a1^(3/2) \[Sigma]X)];
y2[x_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/
   2, ((Sqrt[a1] x)/\[Sigma]X - (a0 \[Delta])/(a1^(3/2) \[Sigma]X))^2];
f[x_] := (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep);
W[x_] := y1[x]*D[y2[x], x] - D[y1[x], x]*y2[x];
SolParticularNonHomo = 
 y1[x]*(\[Integral](y2[x]*(-f[x]))/(a[x]*W[x]) \[DifferentialD]x) + 
  y2[x]*(\[Integral](y1[x]*f[x])/(a[x]*W[x]) \[DifferentialD]x)
```

I would want to verify that the general solution of the nonhomogeneous equation provided by Mathematica is identical to the sum of the the general solution of the homogeneous equation and the particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation. Unfortunately the following does not return `True`:

```
((V1[x] /. SolGeneralHomo[[1]]) + 
    SolParticularNonHomo == (V1[x] /. 
     SolGeneralNonHomo[[1]])) // FullSimplify
```

Any advice?

Comment: I don't see SolParticularNonHomo getting a value.

 Advice: Make your sol-functions functios of x and the parameters. Then solve first for all parameters ->1 excecp for the eigenvalue parameter in oder to see the functions more cleary.  If you have a result test equality by:  Series[a[x]==b[x],{x,0,1}]]

Comment: I corrected the code for SolParticularNonHomo sorry. What should Series[a[x]==b[x],{x,0,1}]] be applied to?

Comment: a[x] and b[x] are the two solutions as functions of x, The two first coefficients of the expansiom at x=0 , in general,  show a False, if  they are different. A True indicates that the free coefficients are the same. Series ever an Equal for the first 13 coefficients Is the fastest way to check equality for solutions of differential equations.